# List all requests in Chrome (plugin) with ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to get a list of all requests that were triggered by a Google Chrome but were blocked by the browser or a plugin? Something like a `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` event?

Background: I want to create an automatism (CI pipeline) that alerts if one or more elements get blocked by AdBlock or others. Sometimes their patterns match elements that are no ads and I want to know if this happens.

Comment: Assuming you write an extension, you can use chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can get monitor all the failed requests using the [chrome.webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)'s [onErrorOccurred event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onErrorOccurred) and examine each one to check if the cause was `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(details =>
{
   // check if it is ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT using details.statusCode or some other way
});
```

Just make sure you specify `webRequest` (along with all the hosts you need) in the `permissions` field in your `manifest.json`.